# verify whether a facebook user shared a link

Tags: facebook, share

I've added the facebook share button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) to my website and I'm trying to determine whether or not someone shares a link. Any ideas on whether this can be done and how? I'm open to using the like button instead of the share button.

Comment: one thing that i haven't mentioned explicitly in that answer, but it's there in the code, is that you have to subscribe to the `edge.create` event. When you see the respective code, you'll understand, ask for clarifications if required.